# Arrange the standard $52$ playing cards given $2$ constraints

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, card-games

We have two constraints to arrange the standard $52$ playing cards:

I. No two adjacent cards have the same suits.

II. An ace does not have an adjacent ace or two. A two does not have an adjacent ace, two, or three. A three does not have an adjacent two, three, or four. A four does not have an adjacent three, four, or five. And so on. A jack does not have an adjacent ten, jack, or queen. A queen does not have an adjacent jack, queen, or king. Finally, a king does not have an adjacent queen or king.

> In how many ways can we arrange these $52$ playing cards where the two
>   given constraints are satisfied simultaneously?

Honestly, I do not know how to solve it. I only tried and got the result: $\boxed{52!-[4(11 \times 10^{12}+2 \times 11^{12})]}$

$\boxed{=80,658,175,170,943,878,571,660,636,856,403,766,975,289,505,440,883,277,754,892,572,986,232}$

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: "Arrange" into what? Into a sequence?

Comment: @WlodAA Yes. How else can the cards be arranged?

Comment: "How else...?" -- use your imagination or blindly believe that others are imaginative, that there are many possibilities.

Comment: If a sequence then is a pair of symmetric (one to another) sequences counted as 1 or as 2?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way.  It makes sense to compute the number of bad sequences and subtract from $52!$ but things are not independent.  There are $50!$ sequences that are bad because they start $AS, 2S$, but many of them will have another pair of cards later that make them bad as well.  It would be a complicated inclusion-exclusion calculation.

Comment: Your number is *waaay* too big. Even using *only* the much simpler rule "no two adjacent cards are both hearts" leas to the much smaller $\frac{40\choose 13}{52\choose 13}\cdot 52!$

Comment: @RossMillikan Do you mean "... bad because they start AS,K'S" instead of "... bad because they start AS,2S"?... Another thing; can we solve for the two constraints as separate entities, and then combine the results some how?

Comment: No, I meant $AS,2S$ because the two cards have the same suit.  $AS, KS$ would apply as well.  No, you can't solve for the two constraints separately because they interact

Comment: If we pretend that things are independent, we can say that the chance the card after an ace or a king is acceptable is $\frac {33}{51}$ and the chance the card after some other rank is acceptable is $\frac {31}{51}$.  The number of good sequences would then be about $$52!\cdot \frac {33^8\cdot 31^{43}}{51^{51}}\approx 1.25\cdot 10^{57}$$ or about one in $1.5\cdot 10^{10}$.  I have no idea how close this is.

Comment: @RossMillikan Well. I am trying to solve it. :)